# xsl cannot sort added nodes

Tags: xml, sorting, xpath, xslt-1.0

After having added some nodes in the xsl, I need to sort them with the xml document nodes to properly format the text output.
Please note that the output can be sorted in 4 different ways depending on the application reading the text document preferred item order.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
    <GroupA>
        <a>A</a>
        <b>B</b>
        <Sub type="Z">
            <bb name="100" dev="1" c="C"><P>N100</P></bb>
            <bb name="50" dev="1" c="C"><P>N50</P></bb>
            <bb name="20" dev="1" c="C"><P>N20</P></bb>
            <bb name="10" dev="1" c="C"><P>N10</P></bb>
            <bb name="5" dev="1" c="C"><P>N5</P></bb>
            <bb name="200" dev="2" c="C"><P>C200</P></bb>
            <bb name="100" dev="2" c="C"><P>C100</P></bb>
            <bb name="50" dev="2" c="C"><P>C50</P></bb>
            <bb name="25" dev="2" c="C"><P>C25</P></bb>
            <bb name="10" dev="2" c="C"><P>C10</P></bb>
            <bb name="5" dev="2" c="C"><P>C5</P></bb>
            <bb name="1" dev="2" c="C"><P>C1</P></bb>
            <bb name="100" dev="1" c="U"><P>N100</P></bb>
            <bb name="50" dev="1" c="U"><P>N50</P></bb>
            <bb name="20" dev="1" c="U"><P>N20</P></bb>
            <bb name="10" dev="1" c="U"><P>N10</P></bb>
            <bb name="5" dev="1" c="U"><P>N5</P></bb>           
            <bb name="2" dev="1" c="U"><P>N2</P></bb>           
            <bb name="1" dev="1" c="U"><P>N1</P></bb>           
        </Sub>
        <Sub type="B">
            <bb name="111" dev="1" c="C"><P>N100</P></bb>
            <bb name="55" dev="1" c="C"><P>N50</P></bb>
            <bb name="22" dev="1" c="C"><P>N20</P></bb>
            <bb name="11" dev="1" c="C"><P>N10</P></bb>
            <bb name="5" dev="1" c="C"><P>N5</P></bb>
            <bb name="222" dev="2" c="C"><P>C200</P></bb>
            <bb name="111" dev="2" c="C"><P>C100</P></bb>
            <bb name="55" dev="2" c="C"><P>C50</P></bb>
            <bb name="25" dev="2" c="C"><P>C25</P></bb>
            <bb name="11" dev="2" c="C"><P>C10</P></bb>
            <bb name="5" dev="2" c="C"><P>C5</P></bb>
            <bb name="1" dev="2" c="C"><P>C1</P></bb>
        </Sub>
    </GroupA>
</Main>
```

Here is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Sub[@type='Z']" name='ABC'>
        <bb c="C" name="1000" dev="1"><P>N1000X</P></bb>
        <bb c="C" name="2" dev="1"><P>N2X</P></bb>
        <bb c="C" name="1" dev="1"><P>N1X</P></bb>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GroupA">
            <xsl:value-of select="a" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="b" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="ABC"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Sub[@type='Z']/bb[@c='C']">
                <xsl:sort select="@dev" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="./P"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>             
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the current output:
A,B,N1000XN2XN1XN100,N50,N20,N10,N5,C200,C100,C50,C25,C10,C5,C1

This is my desired output:
A,B,N1000X,N100,N50,N20,N10,N5,N2X,N1X,C200,C100,C50,C25,C10,C5,C1

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If (!) I understand correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="add">
    <bb c="C" name="1000" dev="1"><P>N1000X</P></bb>
    <bb c="C" name="2" dev="1"><P>N2X</P></bb>
    <bb c="C" name="1" dev="1"><P>N1X</P></bb>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="GroupA">
        <xsl:value-of select="a" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="b" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Sub[@type='Z']/bb[@c='C'] | exsl:node-set($add)/bb">
            <xsl:sort select="@dev" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="P"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>             
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```